# How to hide element correctly in html tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to behind row`2`by default and by clicking tables,it will show itself.

When I try my work like below,row`2` is behind. but the shape of tables distorted.

I would like to align tables and behind row`2` by deafault.

How can I fix it ?

Why this table distorted?

Thanks

```js
$(function() {
  $("table").click(function() {
    $("table tr:eq(1)").toggleClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
td {
padding:5px;
border:solid black 1px;}

table{
border-collapse:collapse;
border:solid black 1px;
cursor:pointer}

tr:nth-child(2):not([class]) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
  <th rowspan="2">header</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
  <th rowspan="2">header</th>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Because you gave the headers a rowspan of 2...

Comment: @MARSHMALLOW - (0) No, it's not (not even close) and (1) Entirely irrelevant. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to toggle the row, I suggest you have a concept of "hide", rather than "show".

Also, get rid of the second row header. Not sure why you need it, if you are spanning 2 rows.

```js
$(() => {
  $('table').click(function(e) {
    $(this).find('tr:eq(1)').toggleClass('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: solid black 1px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  padding: 0.25em;
}

th {
  cursor: pointer
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Header</th>
      <td>01</td>
      <td>02</td>
      <td>03</td>
      <td>04</td>
      <td>05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="hide">
      <td>06</td>
      <td>07</td>
      <td>08</td>
      <td>09</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```